# Best way to get file last modified attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

What would be the best way to get the "last modified" attribute from a file NOT on the web server. My purpose is to display the time stamps of specific network files in a web page. All the JavaScript references I have found are for the current file, or from the web server. I have found references for browsing to, drag-and-drop, etc. But I would like to read the file attribute from the original location. Is this even possible??

**EDIT:**
So now that I have a batch file to create the text file on the web server, how do I get that data into an array so I can display it properly? The data is correct, but it is one long string.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getStatus() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("backupStatus").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="getStatus()">Get QNAP Backup Status</button>
    <ul id="backupStatus">

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my output:

@ECHO 4/13/2016 @FREEMAN1 4/13/2016 @FREEMAN02 4/13/2016 @FREEMAN03 4/7/2016 @FREEMAN4 4/7/2016 @FREEMAN5 4/7/2016 @HR10 4/13/2016 @ACCOUNTING20 4/12/2016 @IT01 4/13/2016 @PROD20 4/12/2016 @UPS10 4/13/2016

Comment: The first step I did was to write a batch file to get the date stamp and write it to a different file on the web server. I used the FORFILES command.

Answer (score 1):

javascript can't go out and read files on a user's computer.  You'd need to read this information on a server and load it in to the page, or via an ajax call.

Comment: Right, so I would need a script on the network to write the attributes to a json or xml file on the web server, then I could use JS to display them??

Comment: yes, if you had a file on the webserver with the data you need then you could use javascript to load that file via ajax.  How that file gets on the webserver is up to you.